# Making MAX IF AS work with multiple inputs

Tags: mysql, sql, if-statement, max

From a MySQL database I am seeking to create a column from a field that meets conditions.

This works:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS report4;

create TABLE report4 as (
  select

    orders_products.orders_id,

   MAX( IF(products_id = 1, final_price, "-") ) AS Membership,

MAX( IF(products_id = 12, final_price, "-" ) ) AS Donation, 

MAX( IF( products_id = 16, final_price, "-" ) ) AS AHCD     

from orders_products

Group by orders_id M);

select * from report4;
```

But I also have other product_id that I wish to inject into the new columns of Membership and Donation.

Product with IDs 2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11 are to go into Membership.
Product with IDs 13,14,15,17,18 are to go into Donation.

It is this secondary part I cannot make work.  Thoughts on what I need to do.

Answer (score 0):

Use this syntax:

```
MAX( IF(products_id IN (2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11), final_price, "-") )
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your inner query to `products_id IN (....)` as shown below

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS report4;    
create TABLE report4 as ( select        
    orders_products.orders_id,
    MAX( IF(products_id IN ( 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11 ), final_price, "-") ) AS Membership,        
    MAX( IF(products_id IN ( 12,13,14,15,17,18 ), final_price, "-" ) ) AS Donation,        
    MAX( IF( products_id = 16, final_price, "-" ) ) AS AHCD        
    from orders_products        
    Group by orders_id M);    
select * from report4;
```

Alternatively, you can also use `products_id = 1 OR products_id = 2 OR ...` instead of `IN`

Answer (score 0):

The answer by @Lobo works for what you are looking for. However, if you have to add any more products, you will have to constantly redo the query, and it is not scalable. You should change your database to store a **products_type** column somewhere, allowing you to simple recategorise a product when you want and have the query run correctly every time.

Add a table called `products_types` and you can use this query instead:

```sql
select
    orders_products.orders_id,
    MAX( IF(pt.types_id = 1, final_price, "-") ) AS Membership,
    MAX( IF(pt.types_id = 2, final_price, "-" ) ) AS Donation, 
    MAX( IF(pt.types_id = 3, final_price, "-" ) ) AS AHCD     
from orders_products
join products_types pt on (pt.products_id = orders_products.products_id)
group by orders_id
```

---

The table definition for types I used was:

```
CREATE TABLE `products_types` (
  `id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `products_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `types_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```